# How to get specific rows?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Suppose I have the following situation:

```
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr class="dark center"></tr>
      <tr class="odd deactivate"></tr>
      <tr class="deactivate"></tr>
      <tr class="odd deativate"></tr>
      <tr class="dark center"></tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

is there a way to exclude from the result the `tr` with class `dark center`?

Actually I used this: `var rows = doc.documentNode.SelectNodes(".//table//tbody//tr");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use not-contains:

```
doc.documentNode.SelectNodes(".//table//tbody//tr[not(contains(@class, 'dark center'))]")
```

Comment: Just tested, and this returns 3 nodes. (As expected)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using LINQ:

```
var rows = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(".//table//tbody//tr")
                .Where(node => node.Attributes["class"].Value != "dark center").ToList();
```